# Systemd script does ExecStop right after ExecStart

Tags: bash, systemd

Here's my Systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=RDS Services

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/rdsdb2/script_rds/
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash start_services.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash stop_services.sh
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can't figure out why it executes sequentially (at system start or when i start it manually) ExecStart and ExecStop.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: Don't run external scripts from systemd that actually call your services. This won't work. Have systemd actually start the services.

Answer (score 77):

`Type=oneshot` is used for units, such as a filesystem check or a cleanup, which execute an action without keeping active processes. Such systemd units will wait until the process specified by `ExecStart` terminates, and then deactivate by running the process specified by `ExecStop`.

`Type=simple` (the default setting) is used when the process configured with `ExecStart` is the main process of the service. Such units will wait until the process specified by `ExecStart` returns, then deactivate by running the process specified by `ExecStop`.

With `RemainAfterExit=yes`, the service will be considered active even when all its processes have returned, and therefore the process specified by `ExecStop` will not run automatically. However, this setting is not recommended since the service will still appear as being active even if it has crashed. This setting is disabled by default.

`Type=forking` is used when the process specified by `ExecStart` is expected to exit after start-up is complete, while its child process(es) continue(s) to run in the background. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons and the recommended choice in your case. The `ExecStop` setting is optional and is used to communicate with the service for a clean termination. The process specified by `ExecStop` will run in case the service crashes. In the absence of any `ExecStop` option, the `systemctl stop servicename` command will simply kill the remaining processes of the unit, as specified by the `KillMode` option.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this GREAT explanation; it helps, cheers. If possible request you to please do add few links for systemctl understanding too.

Comment: Did the ExecStop semantics change here?

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=

Answer (score 13):

if you run

```
[Service]
Type=simple
```

than you need: RemainAfterExit=yes

OR use forking:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
```

Comment: I had "simple" and the app was constantly turning on and off, doing nothing.  WHen I inserted RemainAfterExist=yes, then it actually ran.  Thanks @xsor!

Answer (score 0):

just add: RemainAfterExit=yes
it work like a charm

Comment: Not a good idea because if the process is killed (not stopped), it will still appear as running: 

RemainAfterExit=
Takes a boolean value that specifies whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited. Defaults to no.

Comment: Hi sylvek. Thank you for this answer. Apparently there is a very similar answer but a bit more complete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39969975/3451846 if you don't want downvotes from other people I can suggest to delete this answer (you will also win a badge I think for this usually, the first time at least)